Sufficient condition for uniform convergence of the Stieltjes transform
Let $\mu$ be a probability measure and $\mu_N$ be a sequence of probability measures. For simplicity we may assume them to have compact supports contained in $[-1,1]$. Define
$$G_\mu(z):=\int\frac{\mu(d s)}{z-s}$$
as the Stieltjes transform of $\mu$.
I am looking for a sufficient condition for $G_{\mu_N}\to G_\mu$ uniformly on $\mathbb R+i$ on the complex plane. I would imagine some sort of very 'strong' convergence of the measures $\mu_N\to\mu$. Is there any reference on this problem?

Weak $*$-convergence $\mu_n\to\mu$ (that is, $\int f\, d\mu_n\to\int f\, d\mu$ for all $f\in C[0,1]$) is equivalent to the locally uniform convergence $G_n(z)\to G(z)$ on $z\in\mathbb C^+$.
This is a standard result and thus there must be many references, but it's also easy to prove it from scratch. For the direction you need here, it suffices to observe that obviously $G_n\to G$ pointwise, since $f(s)=1/(z-s)\in C[0,1]$ works as a test function when $z\notin\mathbb R$. A normal families argument then upgrades this to locally uniform convergence.
This is not exactly what you asked for, but notice that we obtain uniform convergence on $\{x+i: -L\le x\le L\}$ for any fixed $L>0$, and since a weak $*$ convergent sequence of measures is bounded, it is also clear that $G_n(x+i)$, $G(x+i)$ are uniformly small on $|x|>L$. Thus $G_n\to G$ uniformly on $\{x+i: x\in\mathbb R\}$, as desired, if $\mu_n\to\mu$ weak $*$.
